# ng-template - how to append/add multiple of templates in one DOM tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I took example from angularjs.org:

```js
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
       Content of the template.
  </script>

<a ng-click="currentTpl='/tpl.html'" id="tpl-link">Load inlined template</a>
<div id="tpl-content" ng-include src="currentTpl"></div>
```

but by click i can add only one template.
How can i append several templates to div id="tpl-content" and how to append first, last, before etc. like with Jquery?

Help please

Comment: have array to store `templateUrls` and use `ng-repeat` to render them

Comment: @PankajParkar, i need to add with ng-click unlimeted times before some condition

Comment: type some examples pls